# How to hide a user's input

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a small dot move across a screen as a test to make a larger idea. How would I hide the previous frame, as well as the user's direction inputs? I will show you the code below so you can have an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
z = 0
spaces = 0
while z == 0:
    print(" " * spaces + "0")
    move = str(input())
    if move == "d":
        spaces = spaces + 1
    elif move == "a":
        spaces = spaces - 1
```

P.S. please don't get mad at me if the answer is incredibly obvious. I have only just started learning and would appreciate if you would not be mean.

Comment: you want to enter input using command line mode or you are using GUI module to create GUI based application. u want to see dot or asterisk in output?

Comment: In general, this is the kind of thing that ncurses and similar libraries are good for -- unless you want to do the work of figuring out where to move the cursor to next to overwrite things that need to go away yourself.

Comment: _Just_ turning off local echo ("hiding a user's input") is much easier than that, but it sounds like that's not all you're looking to do.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure understand. As I mentioned earlier, I am a beginner and have only learned about while statements a day ago (Which I understand is very simple).